# Select all checkboxes from a specific parent

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, automated-tests

acutually i'm facing a selection problem. 
I want to select all checkboxes within a specific parent node.

For example my html code is like:

```
<div class="A">
   <div class="B">
      <label class="xyz"> </label>
      <label class="xyz"> </label>
      <label class="xyz"> </label>
      <label class="xyz"> </label>
      <div class="C">
         <label class="xyz"> </label>
         <label class="xyz"> </label>
         <label class="xyz"> </label>
         <label class="xyz"> </label>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="D">
   <div class="B">
      <label class="xyz"> </label>
      <label class="xyz"> </label>
      <label class="xyz"> </label>
      <label class="xyz"> </label>
   </div>
</div>
```

Now i want to get all labels, where class = "xyz" and parent div class = "A". This means i would like to get the first 8 labels out of my example into a list.
Is it possible to do it like this?

Here is what i tried:

```
List<WebElement> myList = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("div.A>label.xyz"));
```

Unfortunately this is just getting the first 4 labels into the list. 
Therefore my thought is to say " get all labels with class = "xyz" and parent with class = "A" ". I hope you get my point - didn't find anything accurate on the internet.

Answer (score 0):

You can get all the labels using the given below xpath:

```
List<WebElement> myList = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='A']//label[@class='xyz']"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible. Check the below CSS

```
div.A label.xyz
```

**Screenshot:**
[image]